# Rails 4: "Pundit::NotAuthorizedError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, pundit

In my Rails 4 app, there are 5 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I implemented authentication with Devise (so we have access to `current_user`).

Now, I am trying to implement authorization with Pundit (first timer).

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#installation), I installed the gem and ran the `rails g pundit:install` generator.

Then, I created a `CalendarPolicy`, as follows:

```
class CalendarPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  attr_reader :user, :calendar

  def initialize(user, calendar)
    @user = user
    @calendar = calendar
  end

  def index?
    user.owner? || user.editor? || user.viewer?
  end

  def show?
    user.owner? || user.editor? || user.viewer?
  end

  def update?
    user.owner? || user.editor?
  end

  def edit?
    user.owner? || user.editor?
  end

  def destroy?
    user.owner?
  end

end
```

I also updated my `User` model with the following methods:

```
def owner?
  Administration.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id], calendar_id: params[:calendar_id]).role == "Owner"
end

def editor?
  Administration.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id], calendar_id: params[:calendar_id]).role == "Editor"
end

def viewer?
  Administration.find_by(user_id: params[:user_id], calendar_id: params[:calendar_id]).role == "Viewer"
end
```

I updated my `CalendarsController` actions with `authorize @calendar`, as follows:

```
  def index
    @user = current_user
    @calendars = @user.calendars.all
  end

  # GET /calendars/1
  # GET /calendars/1.json
  def show
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendars.find(params[:id])
    authorize @calendar
  end

  # GET /calendars/new
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = @user.calendars.new
    authorize @calendar
  end

  # GET /calendars/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = current_user
    authorize @calendar
  end

  # POST /calendars
  # POST /calendars.json
def create
  @user = current_user
  @calendar = @user.calendars.create(calendar_params)
  authorize @calendar
  respond_to do |format|
    if @calendar.save
      current_user.set_default_role(@calendar.id, 'Owner')
      format.html { redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Calendar was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @calendar }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

  # PATCH/PUT /calendars/1
  # PATCH/PUT /calendars/1.json
  def update
    @user = current_user
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    authorize @calendar
    respond_to do |format|
      if @calendar.update(calendar_params)
        format.html { redirect_to calendar_path(@calendar), notice: 'Calendar was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @calendar }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @calendar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /calendars/1
  # DELETE /calendars/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = current_user
    @calendar.destroy
    authorize @calendar
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to calendars_url, notice: 'Calendar was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

And I included `after_action :verify_authorized, :except => :index` in my `ApplicationController`.

Now, when I log in, I can access `http://localhost:3000/calendars/` but when I try to visit `http://localhost:3000/calendars/new`, I get the following error:

```
Pundit::NotAuthorizedError in CalendarsController#new
not allowed to new? this #<Calendar id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

  @user = current_user
  @calendar = @user.calendars.new
  authorize @calendar
end
```

Obviously, I must have done something wrong.

Problem: I can't figure out what.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had not defined a `create` action in the CalendarPolicy.

Since the CalendarPolicy inherits from the ApplicationPolicy — `CalendarPolicy < ApplicationPolicy` — and the `create` action in the ApplicationPolicy is set to `false` by default, I was getting an error.

Simply adding the following code to `CalendarPolicy` fixed the problem:

```
def create?
  true
end
```

**Bonus tip**: there is no need to add a new action to `CalendarPolicy` since we already have the following code in `ApplicationPolicy`:

```
def new?
  create?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to the params in the model unless you pass them through. You should pass the calendar to the model instance function and you already have access to the user.

```
user.editor?(calendar)

def editor?(calendar)
  Administration.find_by(user_id: self.id, calendar_id: calendar.id).role == "Editor"
end
```

Comment: Ok, so I updated all 3 methods in the `User` model as well as the `CalendarPolicy` as per your answer. But I still get the same error message. Any other idea?

Comment: Are you using pry or debugger? I would put one in the controller, one in the authorize method and one in the model. Then make sure all the variables are set as expected along the way.

Comment: I don't use Pry nor Debugger. I have Byebug installed in development and test. What do you mean by "I would put one in the controller, one in the authorize method and one in the model."?